# How to schedule windows task with trigger logoff/shutdown and without elevation or stored credentials?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, system-sounds, limited-access

Important:
Please be aware, I search for a solution does not need either elevated rights (high-user-integrity) nor user credentials to be entered.
So, this is no duplicate.

Background story:
In Windows 10/11, as most people might noticed by now, soundscheme events for startup/shutdown/logon/logoff got removed due to boot time optimization (opinions on this are likely to differ widely) and the registry trick with ExcludeFromCPL = 0 does not work anymore. I would like to bring them back for the current user by scheduled tasks. I like to get this performed automatically by setup later. For startup/logon/lock/unlock this works like a charm, since MS provides static profiles for that with limited user rights being sufficient.

Problem (and what I tried so far):
Creating scheduled tasks does not seem to provide triggers for logoff/shutdown directly and any solution with **event id 4647 and log called "Security"** need user credentials to be stored on Windows 10 and newer. But it should not, back in Windows XP and 7 this was not necessary either. **Event ids that based on log "System"** are allowed but unfortunately seem to be non-functional. Because my setup should not require elevated rights **also the policy or installed service** is no solution for me.

Do you have any idea how to trigger program execution when shutdown/logoff without either elevation nor stored user credentials needed?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Task Scheduler will not accomplish this, Wrong tool for the job you have. You will likely have to code an App to do what you want.

Comment: It should be an app for windows that creates a themepack. I know there are *.theme and *.themepack files for that, but they are limited to the OS on they were created and my setup will load them for every system from Windows 2000 up to Windows 11.
If task scheduler can not accomplish this, its okay, but is there an alternative?

Comment: I have not seen any app that will do this.

Comment: Thats because I create one, it based on this old tool that loads all windows xp sounds (can't remember the name now), but will come with many more features.